Python 3.6.8 Pip Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) on Virtual Environment
I'm encountering a segmentation fault when trying to use pip inside a Python 3.6.8 virtual environment. The issue occurs when running basic pip commands like pip --version, pip install, or pip list. Here's my setup:

Python version: 3.6.8 (installed with pyenv)
Pyenv version: 2.4.3
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on a VMware virtual machine

Error:
$ pip --version
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ pip install <package>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Steps I’ve tried:
Recompiled Python 3.6.8 with the 16-byte alignment patch for pymalloc.
Upgraded pip but faced the same issue.
Created a fresh virtual environment multiple times.
The pip file:
#!/home/huse/PycharmProjects/pythonVoca/pythonVoca/venv/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.cli.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())

The pip3.6 file
#!/home/huse/PycharmProjects/pythonVoca/pythonVoca/venv/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.cli.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())

Has anyone encountered this issue or know how to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated!

Can you run pip outside of the virtual environment fine? Can you run Python 3.6.8 fine? If you run Python, using the Python shell, can you import pip?

Have you tried python -m pip --version?

I tested the commands both outside and inside the virtual environment:


Outside the virtual environment:

pip --version: pip 18.1 (python 3.6)
Python 3.6.8 runs fine, and I can import pip without any issues.



Inside the virtual environment:

python3.6 -m pip --version: pip 21.3.1 (python 3.6)
The segmentation fault occurs when trying to run pip install or pip list.




But python3.6 -m pip --version works, while pip --version doesn't (when both ran inside the v-env)? Is that correct?

Yes, python3.6 -m pip --version works, while pip --version doesn't.

Extract a [mcve] from the Python/PIP sources. Run pip in a debugger. Sorry, yes, that's pretty generic advise, but that's how development works. Also consider running the stuff on a different machine to rule out environment influences. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Then I would do the following checks: which python; which python3.6; which pip; which pip3.6; let us know what that shows It sounds as if pip is not a pip that belongs to your v-env.

I ran the commands as you suggested: which pip inside the virtual environment: /home/huse/PycharmProjects/pythonVoca/pythonVoca/venv/bin/pip, which python3.6 inside the virtual environment: /home/huse/PycharmProjects/pythonVoca/pythonVoca/venv/bin/python3.6. After deactivating the virtual environment: which pip: /home/huse/.pyenv/shims/pip, which python3.6: /home/huse/.pyenv/shims/python3.6

That seems ok. How about, inside your v-env, python3.6 -m pip list and python3.6 -m pip install <package>?

I ran the commands you suggested, python3.6 -m pip list shows all installed packages, and pip 21.3.1 is correctly listed. I also ran python3.6 -m pip install grpcio==1.48.2, and the package installed successfully without any errors. Everything seems to work fine inside the virtual environment when using python3.6 -m pip.

Then you have a workaround that you can use. Not ideal, and why pip is borked, and how to repair that, is perhaps harder to do. If you want to know about that, first try file $(which pip), and if that is a symbolic link, try file $(which pip3.6).

Thank you! Using python3.6 -m pip as a workaround works perfectly for now. I’ll stick with that while setting up the environment. If I decide to dive into fixing pip later, I’ll definitely try your suggestions. Really appreciate your time and guidance!

Odd thing I noticed: pip's version outside your v-env is 18.1, while inside it's 21.3.1. But with pip crashing, you can't have done a pip install --upgrade pip inside the v-env to upgrade pip. So that's weird. As a bonus check: what do you get when you do python3.6 -m pip --version, outside the v-env?

Outside the v-env, python3.6 -m pip --version gives me pip 18.1. Inside the v-env, it’s pip 21.3.1.

Hm, odd indeed. What about file $(which pip) and file $(which pip3.6) (inside the v-env of course)?

Something strange happened. Previously, pip install <package> gave a segmentation fault, while python3.6 -m pip install <package> worked fine. After removing psbody-mesh==0.4 from requirements.txt, I successfully installed everything. However, when I ran python3.6 -m pip list, a system pop-up said: "Sorry, application init.py has unexpectedly stopped."(Something to that effect) Then I got a segmentation fault. After rebooting, now python3.6 -m pip causes a segmentation fault, but pip works.

After this strange shift, I tried the following commands inside and outside the virtual environment: Inside the v-env: python3.6 -m pip --version -> Segmentation fault (core dumped), pip --version -> pip 21.3.1 (python 3.6). After deactivating the v-env: python3.6 -m pip --version -> pip 18.1 (python 3.6), pip --version -> pip 18.1 (python 3.6)

Inside the virtual environment, both pip and pip3.6 are Python script files:file $(which pip): /home/huse/PycharmProjects/pythonVoca/pythonVoca/venv/bin/pip: Python script, ASCII text executable. file $(which pip3.6): /home/huse/PycharmProjects/pythonVoca/pythonVoca/venv/bin/pip3.6: Python script, ASCII text executable

Ok. In that case, could you have a look inside the files, and if they are small enough (say, 10 lines or so), could you lists both their codes in your question? Because that should point as to why python -m pip works, but pip by itself doesn't.

Ok, I have updated the question with the contents of both the pip and pip3.6 files as requested.

What version of python do you have installed on the system? Can you show how did you create the environment? Are you using venv or virtualenv? I suspect you are running Python 3.6 against a mis-matched stdlib which causes the issue. Probably need to install Python 3.6 (along side, don't downgrade) on the system and create the venv with that version of python. Or use Conda.

@ventsyv
There seems to be only version 3.6.8 of python on the system.: python --version->Python 3.6.8, python3 --version->Python 3.6.8, python3.6 --version->Python 3.6.8. I created the virtual environment using: python3.6 -m venv /home/huse/PycharmProjects/pythonVoca/pythonVoca/venv.

Hm, for an experiment then: the pip file in the v-env, can you edit it and add 3.6 to the end of the first line, no space, like .../bin/python3.6? With that first line changed, does pip now work?

I modified the first line of the pip file to point to python3.6 as you suggested. After that, I tested pip --version and it seems to work correctly now, showing:
pip 21.3.1 from /home/huse/PycharmProjects/pythonVoca/pythonVoca/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Great! That means somewhere along the way, the python executable inside your v-env is messed up (try just python --version inside your v-env; it'll probably crash), while the python3.6 executable inside the v-env is fine. How that happened, I've no idea. You could try to create another new v-env, and see if the same issue holds: python --version crashes and python3.6 --version works fine inside that new v-env.

Hi all, I just wanted to thank you all for your help regarding the segmentation fault issue with pip. After switching to Ubuntu 18.04 and setting up the environment again, the issue seems to have resolved itself. I also tried using conda on my original Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS system, and everything worked fine there too. It's possible that the segmentation fault was due to an OpenSSL and Python version mismatch. The OpenSSL version on Ubuntu 24 is 3.x.x, while I was using Python 3.6.8, which might not be fully compatible. However, I’m still not completely certain of the exact cause.
